# Single Page Application - Large DOM - SLOW

Tags: javascript, html, performance, dom

I'm developing a single page application that uses a lot of widgets (mainly grids and tabs) from the jqWidgets library that are all loaded upon page load. It's getting quite large and I've started to notice after **using** (I emphasize using because it doesn't start to lag after simply being open for any amount of time, but specifically, after opening and closing a bunch of tabs on my page, each tab containing multiple grids loaded thru Ajax that have multiple event listeners tied to each) the site for a couple minutes the UI becomes quite slow and sometimes non-responsive, when the page is refreshed everything works smooth again for a few minutes then back to laggy. I'm still testing on localhost. My initial reaction was that the DOM has too many elements (each grid creates hundreds of divs! And I have a lot of them) so event listeners which are tied to IDs have to search through too many elements and become slow. If this is the case it won't be too hard to fix, is my assumption likely to be the culprit or do I have worse things to fear?

**UPDATE:** here are captures of the memory time line and heap snapshot. On the memory timeline there was no interaction with the site, the two large increases are page refreshes, the middle saw tooth section is just letting my site idle.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does the memory timeline in Chrome say? If it's constantly growing, you have a memory leak and it potentially means lots of dead event handlers and such still hanging out in memory.

Comment: @MattGreer thanks for pointing me to the memory timeline, I always have chrome dev tools open yet I did not know about this feature, I'm pretty new. So the timeline shows the memory growing, then dropping back down over and over, the graph almost representing the shape similar to the blade of a saw. I do notive that the DOM count is fairly high (40,000) which i expected due to all the widgets, yet it doesnt grow out of control. What does grow out of control is the event listener count, when opening/closing tabs the count starts to grow fast! (starts out with about 7000, quickly goes to 11000+

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing any code examples it doesn't sound too bad.

If you have a LOT of jQuery selectors try and make those specific as possible. Especially if you're selecting a lot of items a lot of the time.

For example, if you have a bunch of class "abc", try and specify before that where to look - e.g. are they only found within table cells? are they only found within paragraph tags? The more specific you make your selector the better as if you specify the selector like this:

`$('.class')`

Then it will search the entire DOM for anything that matches `.class`, however, if you specify it as follows: `$('p .class')` then it will only search all paragraph tags for the class.

Other performance killers are wiring up events and then never removing them. If you have any code that removes elements that have event handlers attached to them then best practice is to remove the event handlers when the element is removed. Otherwise you will start piling up orphaned events.

If you are doing a large single page application look to a library like backbone (http://backbonejs.org/) or angular (http://angularjs.org/) to see if this can help you - they alleviate a lot of these issues that people who use plain jQuery will run in to.

Finally, this post (http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/05/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/) is seriously good at outlining out you can write fast, efficient javascript and how to avoid the common performance pitfalls.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

It does sound like you have a memory leak somewhere. Are you using recursion that's not properly controlled or do you have loops that could be ended early, but you fail to break out of them when you find something you're looking for before the loop naturally ends. Are you using something like this:

```
document.getElementById(POS.CurrentTableName + '-Menus').getElementsByTagName('td');
```

where the nodelist returned is huge and you only end up using a tiny bit of it. Those calls are expensive.

It could be your choice of architecture also. Hundreds of divs per grid doesn't sound manageable logically by a human brain. Do you address each div specifically by id or are they just an artifact of the lib you're using and are cluttering up the DOM? Have you checked the DOM itself as you're using it to see if you're adding elements in the hinterland by mistake and cluttering up the DOM with junk you don't use causing the DOM to grow continuously as you use the app. Are you adding the event handlers to the elements numerous times instead of just once?

For comparison, I too have a single page app (Google-Chrome App - Multi currency Restaurant Point of Sale) with anywhere from 1,500 to 20,000 event handlers registered making calls to a sqlite back end on a node.js server. I used mostly pure JS and all but 50 lines of the HTML is written in JS. I tie all the event handlers directly to the lowest level element responsible for the event. Some elements have multiple handlers (click, change, keydown, blur, etc).

The app operates at eye blink speed and stays that fast no matter how long its up. The DOM is fairly large and I regularly destroy and recreate huge portions of it (a restaurant table is cleared and recreated for the next sitting) including adding up to 1,500 event handlers per table. Hitting the CLEAR button and it refreshing the screen with the new table is almost imperceptible, admittedly on a high end processor. My development environment is Fedora 19 Linux.

Comment: The crazy amount of divs is a byproduct of the widget library and I've verified that the elements are removed from the DOM when a grid is removed, or a tab that contains a grid is closed. I also need to clean up empty/old event listeners I'm thinking this is a big contributor cuz my page gets laggy after opening and closing a bunch of tabs (which contain multiple grids, with multiple event listeners tied to each) not just by simply being open for a certain amount of time, but after being USED for a while....

Comment: I set my *.js files up in such a way that one of them handles the creation of things, another handles the operation after creation, and another handles utility aspects. By separating functionality, I broke the app up into manageable chunks easier to debug. Adding handlers is ONLY controlled by the creation code and can't possibly get run more than once per element. Start adding console.log stmts for every event handler creation to see if you're doubling up on the creation side. Add more console stmts in each handler to see if you're event firings make sense as you "work" the app.

Comment: Ok so I have reworked my code so that when a tab is closed, all widgets are destroyed, all handlers created by .on() are removed with .off() and the containing DIV is emptied with .empty(). This has DRAMATICALLY improved the performance alone. Yet there are still some event listeners that are being added (around 150-200) that I can't seem to track down in my code (again, could be byproduct of widget library), is there way to see ALL event listeners added during operations?

Comment: I know of no way to ask the system if there's an event listener on a particular element. In fact, I added an attribute 'data-has-handler' to any element I add an event handler to. Depending on the element, I know that this particular attribute means there is 1, 2, or more handlers attached and I nuke them all when necessary. That's only because I know absolutely that a certain element has a certain collection of handlers. Although your widget library may be benefiting you in one sense, it is also hurting you in another, as it hides things that you possibly need to know about. Is it worth it?

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to see your code, its a little difficult to say exactly.

If the UI takes a little bit before it starts getting laggy, then it sounds likely that you have a memory leak somewhere in your JavaScript. This happens quickly when using a lot of closures as well as nested function and variable references without cleaning them up when your done with them.

Also, event binding to many elements can be a huge drain on browser resources. If possible, try to use event delegation to lower the amount of elements listening to events. For example:
$('table').on('click','td', myEventHandler);

Be careful to make sure that event bindings only occur once as to avoid actions being unintentionally fired many times.

Good luck!